# Vb.net the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net, stream, reader

Hello i wanted to open an csv file and write text in it.
Here is the code:

Try

```
    Dim path As String = "C:\Users\daaemoon\Desktop\Test.csv"
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path))

    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(path)
    Dim s As String = String.Empty

    While reader.Peek() >= 0
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        Dim values As String() = line.Split(";"c)
        listforfalsecsv.Add(values(0))
        s = s + line + Chr(10)
    End While
    reader.Close()
    sw.Write(s)
    sw.Close()


Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

i got the error by the following line:

```
  Dim sw As New StreamWriter(path)
```

If i use the method reader.dispose() after that line             `Dim reader As StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path))`

i come to the while loop, but than i got an error: From an closen Textreader could not been read.

I need help, please help me.

Comment: I think this comes from a fundamental misunderstand on your part.  If you open the file with a stream reader for **reading**, you can't open the same file **again** for writing.  You must read everything you are interested in, manipulate it, and then write it out again.  Remember to close the file after each of these processes.

Comment: Yes but in my example the csv is empty, and the strings that are in my list: listforfalsecsv, i want to write them in the csv data.
Could u give me an example how i can do it right?

Comment: Don't open a StreamWriter to the file until you have closed the StreamReader.  You can't have both open at the same time on one file.  Read in **all** the data, close the reader, process the data, open the writer, write the processed data, close the file.  In that order.

Comment: Or open two different files and then replace the first with the second when the operation is finished.  Up to you.

Comment: Open the StreamReader; read in the whole file; store it somewhere (in a variable); close the streamreader; then open the streamwriter and process the stored file and write it back to the file location. close the streamwriter.

Comment: Okay thanks, it works now!